# XSLT 3.0 Streaming limitation

Tags: xslt, stream, xslt-3.0

I'm currently studying the streaming function in xslt. I'm wondering what are the limitation of it. It seems that it is pretty straight forward transformation, however can it be use to transform a document to another format? like rearranging the position of elements.

Answer (score 4):

Pure streaming is forwards only, node by node, so with pure streaming you could skip nodes, rename/remap them but not rearrange them. On the other hand, you are not restricted to pure streaming, if you have millions of `book` elements but know you want to e.g. sort the `authors/author` children of each `book` you can "materialize" the `authors` element with `copy-of()` and do the sorting on the materialized node (in a non-streaming mode). So pure streaming allows forwards only, one downwards selection which is prettly limiting, but your can mix streaming and non-streaming.

Comment: what do you mean by mix streaming and non-streaming? It'll have to separate transformation? one for streaming and the other one is for non streaming? sorry for being such a noob. I;m still trying to grasp the idea of streaming.

Comment: No, as I tried to explain with the example, your start with a streamable mode to process the input document with streaming in forwards only, node by node processing where only one downwards selection is allowed, but where needed, you can materialize parts of the document with the `copy-of` function or the `snapshot()` function and process those "grounded" nodes with a non-streamable mode as you would normally do. There are also some "restructuring" tasks, e.g. grouping with `group-adjacent` or `group-starting-with`, that (with some restrictions of motionless patterns) work with streaming.

Comment: I would suggest starting with on overview like https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/streaming/ and then see whether some techniques are applicable to your use case; once you run into concrete problems raise a question for every issue you can't solve.